# Does the current phylogenetic system classify only Algae as Thallophytes?

Tags: botany, mycology, classification, algae

I am studying the current system of division of plants.

While studying Thallophytes, I came across some sources which said that Thallophytes consist of Fungi, Algae, and Lichens. Some others (https://asm.org/Articles/2021/January/Three-Reasons-Fungi-Are-Not-Plants), however, stated that Fungi are no longer considered plants.
My question being, which statement is the truth?

It would be quite helpful if I could get an answer, as none of the sources I have visited are intercepting this problem.
There may also be shortcomings in my knowledge, for which I apologise in advance.